# C# Web - localhost:port works, 127.0.0.1:port doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, android-emulator, localhost

I just finished adding C# Web API components (Web API Models & Controllers) to a `localhost` copy of an existing project.

This Web API's GET-methods should be called from an Android app. In [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) it's explained I should use `10.0.2.2` on the Android Emulator to get the computer's `127.0.0.1`.

When I did this, it didn't work for my HttpRequest in the Android app. So I went to the Android browser and typed it directly, and it also didn't work.

Then I tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in my computer's browser, and for some unknown reason it also doesn't work.. Is there a different between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`? I always thought they were one and the same.

Here is the `400 error` I get when using `127.0.0.1`:
[image: 127.0.0.1 error 400 bad request]

And with `localhost` everything works fine.

So, my question: How can I use `localhost` on the Emulator (or, how can I fix the error I get when using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`)? Also, I would like to know the difference between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, since I always thought they were the same.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

---

Edit 1:

In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752960/localhost-and-127-0-0-1-not-the-same) they mention the host file in `System32` of Windows. I opened this file with Notepad++ (as Administrator) and uncommented the lines with `127.0.0.1   localhost` and `::1   localhost`. But unfortunally this didn't fixed the problem and I still can't use `127.0.0.1` on my computer as a replacement for `localhost`. Probably because my problem is the reversed (I can access `localhost`, but not `127.0.0.1`, instead of the other way around.)

---

Edit 2:

In [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382629/1682559) it's explained that the differences between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are:

- `127.0.0.1` will be more easily recognized as an IP in some programming languages.
- `localhost` can be changed to another IP in the computer's host-file (the file mentioned in my *Edit 1*).
- There are some differences between IPv4 and IPv6.

All and all I kinda understand the differences now, I just don't get why my localhost is working, but 127.0.0.1 isn't..

---

Edit 3:

Does it have to do something with the `port` (I use `54408` as `port`)? I've opened `cmd` and did the following tests:

- `ping localhost`: I'm getting a response with 4 times `Reply from ::1: time<1ms`.
- `ping 127.0.0.1`: I'm getting a response with 4 times `Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TIL=128`
- `ping localhost:54408`: I'm getting an error `Ping request could not find localhost:54408. Please check the name and try again.`
- `ping 127.0.0.1:54408`: I'm getting an error `Ping request could not find 127.0.0.1:54408. Please check the name and try again.`

And like I've said before: `127.0.0.1:54408` in the browser gives the error seen in the image above. And `localhost:54408` works just fine..

Still no one with an idea on how to fix this?

---

Edit 4:

Copy of my `hosts-file`, located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
```

The last two lines used to be:

```
#      127.0.0.1     localhost
#      ::1           localhost
```

---

Edit 5 / Semi-Solution:

After Jake C's suggestion I went looking for Visual Studio port configuration and found [the following site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178109%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). At the section "*To specify a port for a Web application project that uses the Visual Studio Development Server*" I followed the instructions and changed the Web option in the Project Properties to `Use Visual Studio Development Server` with my `54408 port`.

This was a great step in the right direction, since `127.0.0.1:54408` homepage now works. However, once I try to log in with the `Google OAuth` on the C# website, I was getting the following error:
[image]

One of my ex-colleagues who worked on the C# web project told me once about [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch). In the answer of this post is stated that I should add the `redirect-urls` (in my case `127.0.0.1`) to the `Google APIs Console`.
Right now I don't have access to this `Console` for my `localhost` project however, since it's obtained through `SVN`. I will ask to one of my supervisors for permission to view the `Google APIs Console` of this C# web project and perhaps edit the `redirect-urls` to include `127.0.0.1`.

Once I've got it completely working I'll accept Jake C's answer, since his explanation of the `Http port configurations` did indeed help me find the answer.

---

Edit 6:

Ok, I've used my own Google APIs Console and created a new Project with a new Client ID. I've added both the `http://localhost:54408/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` and `http:127.0.0.1:54408/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` to the redirect-urls. Then in my C# web project's `App_Start/AuthConfig.cs` I've changed the Client settings to use this new client.

Once again thanks Jake C for your suggestion to change the `http port configurations` in Visual Studio. This did the trick for me.

Comment: Have you had a look in your hosts file in the Windows32 folder, perhaps something is amiss there? Is localhost definetly mapped to 127.0.0.1 or have you deleted it at some point perhaps?

Comment: @Jagga yeah I did (see the first Edit). Everything in the `System32` `hosts-file` is a comment, except for the last two lines: `127.0.0.1   localhost` and `::1   localhost`. I've added the complete file at Edit 4.

Comment: Try putting # to comment the last 2 lines too. On my hosts file they are commented, so I'm assuming they are commented by default.

Comment: @Jagga They used to be commented in my file by default as well. I did try to comment them again like you said, but I'm still getting the same results..

Comment: One of the things you should know, whenever some browsers see an IP address with "." rather than "localhost", regardless of port, they do NOT pass credentials. In IE when using the 127.0.0.1 address it will no longer pass credentials as before across to the server. So there are some weird things that change using that loopback address.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So typically an HTTP 400 Invalid Hostname error usually means you do not have the website set accept all hostnames and/or IP addresses. I presume because this is a C# application you are hosting this on IIS. To fix this open up IIS Manager (Win+R and enter `inetmgr`), expand the server then Sites, then right-click on the the website where your application is hosted and select bindings. In this list there should be an http binding for port 54408, double-click on this. Under IP address make sure All Unassigned is selected, and under Host name make sure the field is blank. Hit OK, then Close. The setting should take effect immediately without needing to reset IIS.

If you are only testing this through Visual Studio's built in web deployment, there are similar settings to the above somewhere in VS (I'm a little rusty on it so I can't remember exactly where or how). Alternatively you can set up a web site in IIS exactly how you want it and then have VS deploy to that website instead of using its own internal server. I think there might be some debugging drawbacks to doing it this way though (once again I'm a little fuzzy on details, I'll edit them in when I remember them or figure it out).

A little background as to why these settings exist:
Sometimes a server needs to host multiple sites that are all to be accessed via port 80. So lets say we have `foo.com` and `bar.com` and they are too small to warrant getting a separate server for both of them. So instead they are both hosted on a sever with an IP address of `1.2.3.4`. Now when you enter the URL `foo.com` into the browser and hit go, it first resolves the host name to `1.2.3.4`, and then it creates a request and part of that request is called the host header. The host header is filled with the hostname of the URL entered, in this case `foo.com`. When the request is received by the server, it looks at the host header and serves back the content for `foo.com`.

Now if you were to try and enter `1.2.3.4` into the browser, it would create a request with a blank host header, because none was specified. When the request is received by the server, it doesn't know what to do because there are two websites being hosted by the server and there is no host header to specify which one the browser is looking for, so instead it returns an error.

This is probably what is happening in your situation. Your website is being hosted under the `localhost` hostname and any other request isn't being responded to. The settings I specified to change are basically telling the server that no matter what IP address (network interface) it comes in on, and no matter what the hostname it is looking for, as long as it is coming in on port 54408, serve this website.

Comment: My C# Website isn't hosted through IIS, and `inetmgr` isn't a valid command on my PC. I will look for the http binding for ports in Visual Studio though, so thanks for that input. Also thanks for the explanation of what might be the cause. +1

Comment: I did find the `Http port configurations` in Visual Studio and managed to get the homepage working with `127.0.0.1` (see edit 5), so thanks a lot for that already. Now I just need to fix a problem with `redirect-urls` within the `Google APIs Console` once I have permission of my supervisor to edit it.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Visual Studio's built in web server (IIS Express), localhost is mapped by default; to enable 127.0.0.1:

1) At path: %USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config

2) Locate config file: applicationhost.config

3) - open config file in editor (I use notepad++)

4) Search for the site port, for example if the url is typically localhost:57578, search "57578" and you should find:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57578:localhost" />
```

5) Change this entry to:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57578:*" />
```

6) Save and exit, restart website.

Note: You will want to repeat this process any time you create a new virtual directory (changing the port number Project/Properties/Web/Project Url), which creates a new entry in the applicationhost.config file.

Comment: Chaging the file `applicationhost.config` in the path %USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config doesn't work for me. but the file in the path `<my solution>\.vs\<project name>\config` worked fine.

Answer (score 17):

In visual studio 2015 with IIS express:
first in project properties change project url from http://localhost:(Port No)
 to : http://127.0.0.1:(Port No)

and click on Create Visual Directory

then go to your solution path and open ".vs" dirctory (directory is hidden) and open "applicationhost.config"

```
<sites>
        <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="####" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\####\####" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5050:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="####(1)" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\####\####" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5050:127.0.0.1" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

and change last binding section of your web app from *:(Port No):localhost to *:(Port No):127.0.0.1

and stop all running project on IIS Express and restart them.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit old post. But my solution could help someone at least a few minutes time.
If you have more than one bindings on the website you are running delete it. Have have only one with IP address: All Unassigned and HostName set to Blank[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into the folder YOUR_PROJECT/.vs/config and open applicationhost.config and change

```
<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58670:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

to 127.0.0.1

```
<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58670:127.0.0.1" />
</bindings>
```

And change this too, to run directly using 127.0.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked form me On visual Studio >= 2017, for dotnet core projects:

1- Edit applicationhost.config located inside .vs\config in your project and add bindings for 127.0.0.1 for http and https:

```
<sites>
    ...
    <site name="Api" id="3"> <!-- your api project -->
        ...
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44380:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55555:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44380:127.0.0.1" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55555:127.0.0.1" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
      ...
</sites>
```

2- edit iisexpress launch settings in vs: from solution explorer under the api project tree

[your project] > properties > launchSettings.json:

```
"iisSettings": {
    ...
    "iisExpress": {
     **"applicationUrl": "https://127.0.0.1:44380",// make sure to use https**
      "sslPort": 44380
    }
  },
```

**make sure to use https in "applicationUrl": "https://127.0.0.1:44380"**

- you can replace the ports as you like

Answer (score 1):

It appears that since release of **Windows Vista**, Microsoft has taken back control of the "mapping" of "localhost" to your internal computer loopback IP's. That is why **the host file has those loopback/localhost entries commented out now in Windows 7, 8, and 10**. That DNS control for these resolutions happens in another TCP/IP transport layer now. The host file still works, it just is not the "default" for what IP gets mapped to "localhost".

There are multiple reasons for this, I have read. One is that years ago they hoped people would move to IPv6 and disable IPv4. If a network admin did this, and users still have IPv4 entries, they would fail. In 2021, that move to IPv6 still hasn't happened on that type of level. But Windows has moved forward by mapping "localhost" for you. The other reason is for security reasons which DNSSEC helped resolve. The way I understand that issue is the host file could be manipulated by malware.

Many Windows PC's now seem to resolve "localhost" to an internal IP of "::1", not "127.0.0.1". That is one problem. The other is the fact "localhost" is added to all servers by defaut, but not the old IPv4 loopback address which is not. Adding the "all unassigned IP's" to your IIs binding will fix this (see other posters). There are separate places for that "All IP's" setting in IIs Express and IIs on your local box. You might need to also add back in the IPv4 loopback mapping in your host file (%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts). Again, Windows now controls that, so adding this might be optional. On my box "::1" is the default.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not an Android nor Windows issue. If you run your localhost by Visual Studio you will not get it available via 127.0.0.1

Instead try to set IIS at your computer, then deploy from Visual Studio to IIS

Alternatively, try UltiDev products:
http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/CassiniDevGuide.htm
http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx

Some peoples managed to use tunneling, but I never tried it and have no clue what to recommend.

Just something which listening to 127.0.0.1 and redirecting data from-to it and localhost