# Can i run my asp.net core mvc web project on 127.0.0.1 instead of local host

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, localhost, recaptcha-v3

I am working on an asp.net core MVC web application, and i need to test the google captcha with it, and one requirement is to access my application inside visual studio 2019 using 127.0.0.1 instead of local host, but when i run my application >> try to access the following `https://127.0.0.1:44363/` >> i got this error `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname`.. any advice how i can access my web application using `https://127.0.0.1:44363/` instead of using `https://localhost:44363/`??
Thanks

Comment: How do you run your application and what OS you use ?

Comment: Try disabling SSL (switch to http). I think that's where your problem is. If the web traffic isn't leaving the computer, it doesn't really introduce a huge security threat.

Comment: @Eugene i run the application using visual studio 2019 and i am using windows 10

Comment: @itsme86 i tried accessing it using http as `http://127.0.0.1:57830/` but i got bad request also

Comment: Is port 57830 HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @itsme86 it is http

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Web - localhost:port works, 127.0.0.1:port doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403912/c-sharp-web-localhostport-works-127-0-0-1port-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can map `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` manually. To do so, go to `hosts` file(location should be something like `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`) and add following line and save the file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: i already has this defined inside my hosts file `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Comment: Check out this similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403912/c-sharp-web-localhostport-works-127-0-0-1port-doesnt-work